# Testing ngForm form of Angular

Tags: angular, forms, testing, jasmine

I have a Login page form like below -

```
<form class="login-form" #loginForm="ngForm">  
  <input [(ngModel)]="login.username" required="true" type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
  <button [disabled]="!loginForm.form.valid" label="Login" class="btn-login" type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Now the test case for checking the disabled/enabled status of Login button -

```
describe('Login button status', () => {
  let loginBtn, userInputElm;
  beforeEach(() => {
    loginBtn = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.btn-login');
    userInputElm = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('input#username');
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should be enabled if "username" is provided', () => {
    userInputElm.value = 'validusername';
    // component.login.username = 'validuser'; <-- also tried this
    fixture.detectChanges();
    // loginBtn = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.btn-login'); <-- tried this (same result)
    // button should be enabled
    expect(loginBtn.disabled).toBe(false); <-- Button still remains disabled
  });
});
```

As, the angular is not getting notified of changes of `#username` field, it is not changing status of the Login button. What I can do to succesfully test this? Need to notify Angular about changes.

I have already imported the `FormsModule` in the TestBed configuration module.

I know I can do things in Angular way using [Angular FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup), but I would like to keep the form as it is if possible.

Comment: an advice, use reactive forms, they can be tested much easier than template driven forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try. You should trigger the [change event programmatically](https://kirjai.com/testing-angular-forms-with-dispatchevent/) on the input field.

```
it('should be enabled if "username" is provided', () => {
    userInputElm.value = 'validusername';
    userInputElm.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    fixture.detectChanges();

    // button should be enabled
    expect(loginBtn.disabled).toBe(false);
});
```

Comment: I am really sorry Amit that I forgot to add this tried option in my question. This also fetched button with the disabled attribute(which is correct). The problem is that Angular is not getting notified of state/value changes.

Comment: Yes, updating dom element that way from your spec wont be reflected in view. You should dispatch input value change event  `userInputElm.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));`.

Comment: Thanks Amit, this solution works perfectly. I have edited your answer to provide more details into it.